# Creating a dashboard-style display with automatically-updated excel content

Tags: 2013

We are new to sharepoint and our customer has a 2013 install, they would like to create a "dashboard" style page that they can bookmark for an executive that needs to view tabular data from excel.  This page should ideally be able to contain parts of multiple spreadsheets stored in sharepoint. They envision a page with a half dozen small rectangular sections, each holding some chart or tabular data from multiple spreadsheets.  Whenever an employee updates a spreadsheet's content, the dashboard would update (either immediately, or the next time the dashboard page was reloaded in the browser.)

Is this possible?  We are trying to insert a web part of type excel but keep running into permission problems, which we cannot figure out how to solve, and we don't even know if this is the right approach or if what we are trying to do is even possible in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a full width webpart page that has a bunch of spreadsheets linked through Excel Web Access webparts, then on the page you could have a CEWP that runs a simple script that will refresh every 5-10 minutes, so they can see updates.

The linking of Excel data could be on another master spreadsheet, but you can link the Excel web access webpart to a Named Item, just create one Excel Web Access webpart per Named item, chart, table, etc.

Comment: thanks very much, we'll try this.  we are just now trying to get past permissions to "add and customize pages"